# How to remove the outline on my video player

Tags: html, css

I have got a basic video player and when clicked to play the video then i get a kind of blue outline, which i wish to remove.

I have tried the basic like `outline:none`, but nothing has changed. I have also researched on the internet, including w3 schools and it tell may to use the outline attribute. Am I putting it in the wrong place?

HTML

```
<div class="video-container">
    <figure id="videoContainer" data-fullscreen="false">
        <video id="video" controls autoplay preload="metadata" poster="img/poster.jpg">
            <source src="../videoplayer/intro.mkv" type="video/mp4">

            <!-- Offer download -->
            <a href="..videoplayer/intro.mkv">Download MP4</a>
        </video>
        <ul id="video-controls" class="controls">
            <li><button id="playpause" type="button">Play/Pause</button></li>
            <li><button id="stop" type="button">Stop</button></li>
            <li class="progress">
                <progress id="progress" value="0" min="0">
                    <span id="progress-bar"></span>
                </progress>
            </li>
            <li><button id="mute" type="button">Mute/Unmute</button></li>
            <li><button id="volinc" type="button">Vol+</button></li>
            <li><button id="voldec" type="button">Vol-</button></li>
            <li><button id="fs" type="button">Fullscreen</button></li>
        </ul>
        <figcaption>

        </figcaption>
    </figure>
```

css

```
.video-container{
    background-color: #191919;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
}
figure {
    max-width:1024px;
    max-width:64rem;
    width:250%;
    height:auto;
    margin:20px 0 0;
    margin:1.25rem 0 0;
}
figcaption {
    display:block;
    font-size:16px;
    font-size:1rem;
}
video {
    width:1150px;
    margin-top:200px;
    margin-left: 390px;
}
video#video {
    outline: none
}
/* controls */
.controls, .controls li {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.controls {
    display:none;
    list-style-type:none;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:transparent;
}
.controls li {
    float:left;
    width:10%;
    margin-left:0.3%;
}
.controls li:first-child {
    margin-left:0;
}
.controls .progress {
    width:38%;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.controls button {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
.controls progress {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
    height:1.25rem;
    margin-top:2px;
    margin-top:0.125rem;
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    overflow:hidden;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
}
.controls progress span {
    width:0%;
    height:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#2a84cd;   
}

/* fullscreen */
html:-ms-fullscreen {
    width:100%;
}
:-webkit-full-screen {
    background-color:transparent;
}
/* hide controls on fullscreen with WebKit */
figure[data-fullscreen=true] video::-webkit-media-controls {
    display:none !important;
}
figure[data-fullscreen=true] {
    max-width:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
figure[data-fullscreen=true] video {
    height:auto;
}
figure[data-fullscreen=true] figcaption {
    display:none;
}
figure[data-fullscreen=true] .controls {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:2%;
    width:100%;
    z-index:2147483647;
}
figure[data-fullscreen=true] .controls li {
    width:5%;
}
figure[data-fullscreen=true] .controls .progress {
    width:68%;
}
```

Screenshot of the outline that i wish to remove
https://i.stack.imgur.com/laxtY.jpg

Any help  appreciated and thanks in advance

Comment: It's because that element is focussed currently. Which browser are you using? I think this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/q/11336017/2427065

Comment: Possible duplicate of [outline:none; does NOT WORK - Only -webkit-appearance:none; is working - what is wrong here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336017/outlinenone-does-not-work-only-webkit-appearancenone-is-working-what-is)

Comment: `.controls progress span { background-color:#2a84cd;}` delete this background-color in your css and tell me what happens

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
.video-container:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Please explain why your answer is correct instead of just saying "try this." Especially since when the OP says in the original post "I have tried the basic like `outline:none`, but nothing has changed."

Answer (score 2):

An outline is a line that is drawn around elements, outside the borders, to make the element "stand out".

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_outline.asp

```css
.video-container{
  background-color: #191919;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  // add this
  outline :none;
}
```

As Marko Sikman said you can also add

```css
.video-container:focus{
  outline :none;
}
```

focus tells that when you click on that element then the outline appears, so if you set it to none then it doesn't appear on click

Comment: Please explain why your answer is correct instead of just saying "try this."

Answer (score -2):

Try adding the following to your CSS:

```
#video:focus {
    outline:none !important;
}
```

Comment: `!important` is never the solution